# Forward email with its attachment and text from template

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I need to forward a selected email (which I call `origEmail`) with its attachment and additional text.

The code leaves off the attachment of `origEmail`.

The body of the forward email is taken from a template email and is merged with `origEmail` body.

How do I include the attachment of `origEmail`?

```vb
Sub forwardemailwithattachment()

    Dim origEmail As MailItem
    Dim forwardEmail As MailItem

    Set origEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)
    Set forwardEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("insert here template location")

    forwardEmail.To = "insert here email address of recipient"

    forwardEmail.Subject = forwardEmail.Subject & origEmail.Subject

    forwardEmail.HTMLBody = forwardEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.Forward.HTMLBody

    forwardEmail.Display

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
pathto = "C:\YourPath\"
For i = 1 to origEmail.Attachments.Count
  origEmail.Attachments(i).SaveAsFile pathto & origEmail.Attachments(i).FileName
  forwardEmail.Attachments.Add pathto & origEmail.Attachments(i).FileName
  Kill pathto & origEmail.Attachments(i)
Next i
```

Comment: thank you black cat, it's a bit complicated for my level of knowledge, but I will try to use it once I have more experience, now I have problems to understand it

Answer (score 0):

Call `MailItem.Forward` (returns the new forwarded `MailItem` object with the suitably formatted body and the attachments), then modify its `HTMLBody` with your extra data. Keep in mind that two HTML strings cannot be simply concatenated - they must be merged.

Comment: the origEmail contains images but they all get lost in the final forwardEmail, they are replaced by the sentence "the linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been ...", would you happen to know why ?

Comment: Please show your code that calls Forward.

Comment: here's the code I am using:

Comment: Sub forwardemailwithattachment()

Dim origEmail As MailItem
Dim forwardEmail As MailItem
Dim templateEmail As MailItem

Set origEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)
Set templateEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("insert here the location and the name of the templateEmail.oft")
Set forwardEmail = origEmail.Forward()

forwardEmail.To = templateEmail.To

forwardEmail.HTMLBody = templateEmail.Forward.HTMLBody & origEmail.Forward.HTMLBody

forwardEmail.Display

End Sub

Comment: You cannot concatenate two HTML strings and expect a valid HTML document. Which attachments are missing? From the template message? You never copy them.

Comment: the images of the TemplateEmail are missing

Comment: these images are in the body of the TemplateEmail

Comment: Is it because `forwardEmail.Attachments.Count = 0`? Or because `forwardEmail.HTMLBody` is corrupted and the image references are wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To create a new item in case of forwarding you need to use a corresponding method for that, see [MailItem.Forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.forward(method)).

Your code may look like that:

```
Sub forwardemailwithattachment()

    Dim origEmail As MailItem
    Dim forwardEmail As MailItem

    Set origEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)
    Set forwardEmail = origEmail.Forward()

    forwardEmail.To = "insert here email address of recipient"

    forwardEmail.Display

End Sub
```

Note, in case of calling the `Forward` method there is no need to set the message body or set the `Subject` property separately. They will be set by default based on the original item properties.

Comment: thank you, it works, just I have two polite comments: a typo on line 5, origEmail instead of origEmails, I mean without "s" ? Then I see that in your code you have left out one line that was present in my code and that I needed to get the text of a template email, the line is Set forwardEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("insert here template location").

Comment: Corrected. Glad it helped!

Comment: there is still a small problem, the origEmail contains images but they all get lost in the final forwardEmail, they are replaced by the sentence "the linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been ...", would you happen to know why ?